# Kadira Flow Router "There is no route for the path: /"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, routes, flow-router

I have a meteor application which is structured like so:

```
client
--main.js
imports
 \startup
   \client
    --index.js
    --routes.js
 \ui
   \pages
    --home-page.html
    --home-page.js
    --login-page.html
    --login-page.js
   \layouts
    --app-layout.html
    --app-layout.js
```

Js and Html files imports\ui have valid html pages and logic for them.
So now i want to setup routing manually, according to the official meteor site i have changed main.js like so:

```
import '/imports/startup/client';
```

And my index.js in imports\startup\client just includes routes.js:

```
import './routes.js';
```

And routes.js:

```
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { BlazeLayout } from 'meteor/kadira:blaze-layout';

import '../../ui/pages/login-page.js';
import '../../ui/layouts/app-layout.js'
import '../../ui/pages/home-page.js'

FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: 'Main.login',

        triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
            if (Meteor.userId()) {
                redirect('/home');
            }
        }],
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('Login_Page');

    }
});
FlowRouter.route('/home', {
    name: 'Main.home',
    triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            redirect('/');
        }
    }],
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('App_Layout', { body : 'HomePage' });

    }
});
```

When i run meteor from my project dir, and visit url:3000, nothing is displayed,  and i see in the javascript console in browser :

```
There is no route for the path: /
kadira_flow-router.js:517:5
router.js/Router.prototype._notfoundRoute
http://host:3000/packages/kadira_flow-router.js:517:5
router.js/Router.prototype._updateCallbacks/<
http://host:3000/packages/kadira_flow-router.js:705:5
index.js/Route.prototype.middleware/<
http://host:3000/packages/kadira_flow-router.js:1488:52
```

The meteor version is METEOR@1.6.0.1 
I cant understand, i have done all according to example on official site, but still can't get this to route. It looks like main.js doesn't even include the routes.js.

Here is my project package list:

```
accounts-password      1.5.0  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui            1.2.0  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
blaze-html-templates   1.1.2  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
dynamic-import         0.2.1  Runtime support for Meteor 1.5 dynamic import(...) syntax
ecmascript             0.9.0  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
es5-shim               4.6.15  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
jquery                 1.11.10  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
kadira:blaze-layout    2.3.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
kadira:flow-router     2.12.1  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
meteor-base            1.2.0  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience      1.0.5  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                  1.3.1  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
ostrio:meteor-root     1.0.6  [Server] Get current path on server, where is Meteor application is running
practicalmeteor:mocha  2.4.5_6  Write package tests with mocha and run them in the browser or from the command line with spac...
reactive-dict          1.2.0  Reactive dictionary
reactive-var           1.0.11  Reactive variable
sacha:spin             2.3.1  Simple spinner package for Meteor
shell-server           0.3.1  Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.
standard-minifier-css  1.3.5  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js   2.2.3  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                1.1.3  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
vsivsi:job-collection  1.5.2  A persistent and reactive job queue for Meteor, supporting distributed workers that can run any...
```

Comment: "It looks like main.js doesn't even include the routes.js." then write `throw new Error()` in routes.js and see, if the error occurs on your console. If so, there is an import problem. If not we need to dig deeper into the code to see what's happening there.

Comment: @Kamabokoo got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to import the html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by deleting the "meteor" prop inside my package.json:

```js
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
```

After I removed this and add a name to my routes (that you already have) my FlowRouter works fine.